# Animated objects with sceneform

Tags: arcore, sceneform

Is it possible to animate 3d objects with sceneform in arcore? If yes then, are there any documentations available? and if no then, is google planning to add animation support in sceneform anytime soon?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there's not too much support for it besides rotating, moving and/or resizing stuff. This is all done in the Sceneform solar sample. For more advanced support watch this ticket: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/11#issuecomment-449075135

Answer (score 0):

ArCore and Sceneform are now able to support animations after their latest release.
SceneForm v1.7.0 is capable of using animated FBX models.

> #### New APIs and capabilities
>
> - Sceneform includes an optional animation library, com.google.ar.sceneform:animation which enables animation playback.
> - Added ModelAnimator and AnimationData classes. Sceneform now has the ability to play animated models.

A sample for using animations has been provided in the [Sceneform Samples](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/animation).
You can also refer to the other various changes made in the latest release of Sceneform [here](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/releases).

#### Edit:

If by animation, you actually mean rotating, moving or scaling your rendered models, then you can use a [TransformableNode](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode) instead of a normal `Node` and Sceneform will take care of that for you.